# Как поменять местами слова в строках используя sed

Tags: shell, sed

Существует nginx конфиг.

```
upstream {
    server 1.1.1.1:8080;
    server 2.2.2.2:8080 backup;
}
server {
    ...
```

Необходимо переместить слово `backup` с `2.2.2.2` в `1.1.1.1` и наоборот, используя sed.
Например, если:

```
server 1.1.1.1:8080 backup;
server 2.2.2.2:8080;
```

сделать:

```
server 1.1.1.1:8080;
server 2.2.2.2:8080 backup;
```

и если:

```
server 1.1.1.1:8080;
server 2.2.2.2:8080 backup;
```

сделать:

```
server 1.1.1.1:8080 backup;
server 2.2.2.2:8080;
```

Как это возможно сделать?

Дополнение: Заранее не известно где будет находится `backup`. Статическая информация это только IP адрес `1.1.1.1` и `2.2.2.2`.

Comment: вместо переместить рассматривай проблему как «добавить там где `1.1.1.1` и убрать там где `2.2.2.2`»... общая сложность скрипта будет зависеть от вариантов разнообразия конфигов...

Comment: Если рассматривать решение убрать и добавить, тогда можно следующим образом:
`sed -e s/backup//g -e s/"1.1.1.1:8080"/"1.1.1.1:8080 backup"/g`
Но как я ранее говорил, не известно где будет находится `backup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В простом варианте, если не проверять, что всё находится внутри секции `upstream` и когда ничего кроме `backup` в этой строчке стоять не может, можно сделать как-то так:

```
sed -re 's/(server\s+1\.1\.1\.1:8080).*/\1 backup.*;/;s/(server\s+2\.2\.2\.2:8080)\s+backup;/\1/;'
```

---

Перемещение слова туда и обратно можно рассматривать как «добавить если его нет и убрать в противном случае»:

```
sed -re '/server (1\.1\.1\.1|2\.2\.2\.2):8080/{s/\s*backup//;t;s/\s*;/ backup;/}
```

Более глубокий анализ на случай, если `backup` окажется в обеих строчках, потребует отдельного цикла чтения — на `sed` вещь возможная, но проще будет уже воспользоваться `perl`'ом или `awk`.

Comment: Ваш пример изменяет только для `1.1.1.1`, он не будет работать, если `backup` находится после `2.2.2.2`

Comment: @VitaliyKalyuzhnyak, так надо «включить в 1.1.1.1 и выключить в 2.2.2.2» или «перекинуть с 2 на 1 или обратно»?

Comment: Цель одна, если в `1.1.1.1` есть `backup`, то убрать, и если в `2.2.2.2` нет `backup`, то дописать

Comment: @VitaliyKalyuzhnyak, гм... в вопросе с точностью до наоборот... что-то я окончательно перестал понимать чего ты хочешь...

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, вопрос не до конца коректен. Добавил максимально подробное описание!

Comment: @VitaliyKalyuzhnyak, дополнил... идея аналогична ответу *alexander barakin*, но более компактный и читаемый вариант...

Comment: да это именно то, что нужно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

подчазадачи:

1. добавить символы `\ backup` в строку, содержающую текст `1\.1\.1\.1`, после этого текста, сразу перед символом `;`:

   ```
   $ sed '/1\.1\.1\.1/s/1\.1\.1\.1[^;]*/& backup/' file
   ```
2. убрать символы `\ backup` из строки, содержащей текст `2\.2\.2\.2`, после этого текста, но до символа `;`:

   ```
   $ sed '/2\.2\.2\.2/s/\(2\.2\.2\.2[^;]*\) backup/\1/' file
   ```

---

можно и одной командой, разделив программы точкой с запятой:

```
$ sed '/1\.1\.1\.1/s/1\.1\.1\.1[^;]*/& backup/;/2\.2\.2\.2/s/\(2\.2\.2\.2[^;]*\) backup/\1/' file
```

---

если требуется «триггер», убирающий символы `\ backup`, если они были, и добавляющий в противном случае, то можно добавить команду условного перехода `t`:

```
$ sed '/1\.1\.1\.1/{s/\(1\.1\.1\.1[^;]*\) backup/\1/;to;s/1\.1\.1\.1[^;]*/& backup/};:o' file
```

аналогично и для строки, содержащей текст `2\.2\.2\.2`. если сводить это в одну команду, то метку `:o` надо оставить только одну:

```
$ sed '/1\.1\.1\.1/{...};/2\.2\.2\.2/{...};:o' file
```

Comment: Данное решение подходит если мы заранее знаем где стоит `backup`, но все беда в том, что бы нам это не известно.

Comment: дополнил ответ.